# Amazon S3 Redirect on Access Denied

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is there some way to redirect a user that reaches gets the AccessDenied-error on a bucket? Some bucket-config maybe? Are there any sort of redirect features at all for s3/cloudfront?

I thought it might be a way to solve the problem with not being able to have zero-keys so that you can show your users something usable if they go to the "root" of the subdomain you're using for s3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible (yet?). Sorry.

Answer (score 11):

Now Amazon S3 - Support for Website Redirects

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/10/amazon-s3-support-for-website-redirects.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Amazon S3 or cloudfront